# OpenGLES draw arrow base on touch

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw arrows like this:

[image]

I've tried use normal vertex & fragment shader like [google samples](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/OpenGL/HelloOpenGLES20/src/com/example/android/opengl/Square.java#30), with **5 points** for vertex coords:

```
static float vertexCoords[] = {
        -0.3f, 0.2f, 0.0f,   // bottom left swing
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top
        0.0f,  -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // back to top again
        0.3f, 0.2f, 0.0f    // bottom right swing
};
```

[image]

Then draw using `GL_LINE_STRIP`:

```
int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
int vertexCount = 364 * 3 / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
```

I've successfully achieve it, but **only fixed arrow**.

**Now I want to draw this arrow by user's touch**: touch down at point A, move to point B, then we must draw an arrow from A to B. If drawing a single line, it will be more easier, but in this case I must draw 2 'arrow swing lines' at point B. Assume that the angle between each 'arrow swing line' to the central line is **45 degrees**.

I've think about 2 ways now:

- Use the fixed vertex coords above, put them to a matrix to **rotate** & **translate** base on user touch.
- Use coordinate of point A and B, and the 45 degree angle to find the coordinate of 2 point at the end of 'arrow swing'.

---

**Update 1:**

I'm following the 1st approach, and done **recalculate the vertex coordinates** using `Matrix` rotation & translate. But now I face another problem, I need to dynamically change the **width / thickness** of arrow line. But `glLineWidth()` is not guarantee to be implemented on all devices.

---

I'm new to OpenGLES, any one know how to achieve this?

Comment: So the length of the arrow varies, but the peak should keep its shape?

Comment: Yes, @Rabbid76 , the peak only rotate with the center line, but not change size

Comment: This are just 4 points, I recommend to recalculate them and to update the buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've done recalculate the vertex coordinates using `Matrix` rotation & translate. But now I face another problem, I need to dynamically change the width of     arrow line. But `glLineWidth()` is not guarantee to be implemented on all devices.

Comment: Form the lines by polygons. Draw rectangular shapes (2 triangles) instead of the lines.

Comment: @Rabbid76 To form these lines by polygons, I need **4 float numbers** which represent 2 coordinates **for a single line**. Right? So If I need to draw an arrow (3 lines), I need **12 float numbers**?